# What is the difference between the role of Lord Shani and Lord Yama?

Tags: karma, dharma, shani, yama

We know from various scriptures that Lord Yamaraja gives us the results of our karma (either good or bad) when we die.
But at the same time, it is said that Lord Shani is 'Karmafala Daata' and gives the results of our karmas when we are alive.

So how does this system of Karmafala (calculating one's virtues and sins and giving result) works and what is the difference between the roles of both the brothers?

Comment: Please stop considering those TV serials to be on par with the authentic scriptural texts. Shanaischara is a graha whose position in the horoscope exceptionally affects the daiva of the person. Yama alongside Chitragupta has the ability to hand out judgements in the afterlife to some extent. Only the Panchadevatas (Bhagavana Vishnu, Bhagavana Sadashiva, Bhagavana Ganesha, Bhagavana Surya & Bhagavati Adyashakti) are the Supreme 'karmaphaladata's

Comment: @AnubrataBit Which serial ??  I did not watch any serial and put this question . I was talking in general terms . I too oppose the rubbish serials made nowadays : )